# Error defining function outside the class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to define a function which returns a pointer to a structure

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class abc
{
private:
    struct n
    {
        int data;
    };
public:
    n* print();
};

n* abc::print()
{
    n* q = new n;
    q->data = 7;
    return q;
}
```

When this program is compiled "identifier n is undefined" error is shown. Why does the program compile successfully when the same function abc is defined inside the class ?

Comment: sorry typing error. corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n` is a nested class. You need to qualify it with `abc::n`.

***Note: The name and scope of a class is also a [`namespace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)***, since `n` is nested in `abc`, `abc` is now *like* the `namespace` of `n`.

Full example:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class abc
{
private:
    struct n
    {
        int data;
    };
public:
    n* print();
};

abc::n* abc::print()
{
    abc::n* q = new abc::n;
    q->data = 7;
    return q;
}
```

Comment: You are overdoing it. Once inside the abc:: scope you do not need to qualify n again and again.

Comment: Yea, there is redundancy there, but I was trying to demonstrate the namespace thing....

Answer (score 1):

Because the returned n, when defined outside the class, has a different scope. You can fix this by prefixing it with the correct scope:

```
abc::n* abc::print()
{
    n* q = new node;
    q->data = 7;
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the class there is no `n` symbol, so you need to fully qualify it like `abc::n`.